# How to solve local caching?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, caching, react-native-image

My question is the next:

**Situation:**
I have an `ImagesScreen` where I can upload some additional photos, delete them, etc.
When someone add a new photo (from the gallery, react-native-image-crop), I want to make a copy from the image, save it to the local storage (so even if someone delete the image from the gallery I got my own copy in my local storage).

**Why:**
I do not want to immediately send the photos toward the API, I just want to backup them every day, so when I make a copy from the selected photo(s) I want to retrieve the uri of the local stored image. (not the uri of the image in the gallery)

How would you guys handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its complicated, try https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs, is suitable for you.

there you can handle cached dirs, tmp dirs, delete files/save files

Comment: Will do, just as you answered it in 5 mins, and I need to wait 5 more minutes before being able to accept it :D